# create input box inside the lable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a label and placed outer the input check box, like

what I was trying this, My html is

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

My jquery is

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').after('<label class="label-select"><span></span></label>');
```

Now the output is

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label class="label-select">
<span></span>
</label>
```

But I want like this

```
<label class="label-select">
<input type="checkbox">
<span></span>
</label>
```

So how may I write jquery for this. I dont like to change HTML.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wrap()` not `after()`:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<label class="label-select"></label>').after('<span></span>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BnW2P/2)

Comment: Thank you, But the output html is like this `<label class="label-select"><span><input type="checkbox"></span></label>`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that wrap function. :)

Comment: This soln is perfect. @Selva Accept this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery.wrap() you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').after('<span></span>').wrap('<label class="label-select"></label>');
```

**EDIT**
Got the two back to front sorry, should be

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<label class="label-select"></label>').after('<span></span>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Your html is like this `<label class="label-select"><input type="checkbox"></label><span></span>`

Comment: Edited it to fix. Had the .after and the .wrap the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap the element (checkbox) inside the label.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<label class="label-select"><span></span></label>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<label class="label-select"></label>').wrap('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use jquery append() method to append html inside a block. Try this one,

```
$('.label-select').append('<input type="checkbox"><span></span>');
```